# Create new ILO5 user via HPE OneView

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a Python script to create a user on ILO5 managed directly by OneView.

The restrictions I have are these:

1. I don't have an ILO username and password.
2. To access the ILO, I have to go through OneView or the onboard administrator of the C7000.
3. The script must work for any blade.

This is my script but it gives an error when I try to connect to the ILO from OneView.

I'm trying to consult the OneView 6.6 REST API but I can't find any solution.

Can you help me? I've been looking for a solution for days without success.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# OneView Login
oneview_host = "https://<IP>"
oneview_username = "<username>"
oneview_password = "<pass>"

# Token from OneView
def get_oneview_session_token():
auth_url = f"{oneview_host}/rest/login-sessions"
auth_data = {"userName": oneview_username, "password": oneview_password}
response = requests.post(auth_url, json=auth_data, verify=False)  # Disabilita la verifica SSL se necessario
if response.status_code == 200:
return response.json()['sessionID']
else:
raise Exception("Failed to authenticate with OneView")

# Function to create the iLO user
def create_ilo_user(ilo_ip, username, password, user_login="test", user_password="test"
ilo_url = f"https://{ilo_ip}/redfish/v1/AccountService/Accounts/"
new_user_data = {
"UserName": user_login,
"Password": user_password,
"Oem": {
"Hp": {
"LoginName": user_login,
"Privileges": {
"LoginPriv": True,
"RemoteConsolePriv": True,
"UserConfigPriv": True,
"VirtualMediaPriv": True,
"iLOConfigPriv": True,
"VirtualPowerAndResetPriv": True
                }
            }
        }
    }
response = requests.post(ilo_url, json=new_user_data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), verify=False)  # disable SSL check if necessary
if response.status_code in [200, 201]:
print(f"User {user_login} created successfully on {ilo_ip}.")
else:
print(f"Failed to create user on {ilo_ip}. Response: {response.text}")

# Ilo login
token = get_oneview_session_token()
ilo_ip_list = ["<iplist,iplist>"] 

for ilo_ip in ilo_ip_list:
create_ilo_user(ilo_ip, oneview_username, oneview_password)
```

I tried to use the REST API reference without sucess
https://support.hpe.com/unmanagedDoc/display/public/dp00003325en_us/index.html#about

Comment: Can you check the formatting of above code? In particular Python is very sensitive to formatting. Also, what are the errors you get? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].